# after migrating to D7 all images are missing

Tags: migrations, media

After migrating to D 7.20 all my images are gone, actually they exist on the server but are not being displayed at all. I have a multi-site installation and I've successfully migrated all the content and re-enabled the modules. 
I have a page where all the users pictures should be displayed and none of them are being displayed. So, I've created a new account and uploaded a picture for it and this new picture appears. What should I be looking at? How can I migrate all the pictures to the new installation properly ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you migrating from a previous D7 version, from D6 or what?

Comment: Hi Triskelion. From D6 ...

Comment: D6 to D7 migrations are not straight forward. I have upgraded several sites and sometimes had to have several kicks at the can before the migration worked. In most cases some manual work was required post-migration to massage the results. Before migrating, upgrade your D6 sites to the latest versions of all modules, and eliminate any modules which do not have a D7 equivalent. Then once you have the D6 sites behaving correctly, start your migration efforts. For your sake, I hope your D6 sites are still live!

Comment: I was pretty much aware of this my friend. That's why I've cloned my machine and did the migration on a 'pre-release' environment. I do have backups. However, although I did followed closely every step to safely migrate to D7 the only thing that I haven't yet sorted is this images issue not being displayed which is driving me insane. There are hundred if not thousand of pictures which I have no idea why are not being displayed. I've exhausted all work-arounds found.

Comment: Are there any log (watchdog or syslog) messages when you try to view the images? Have you compared the storage of image information between the migrated images and the one you uploaded in D7. Did the migrated images come across as imagefield or filefield? Trying to give you some clues as to where to look.

Comment: Would be involved the new image style generation system (http://drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes) ? Try to add this code on settings.php


`$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;`


Does it help?

Comment: Hi FiNeX. I've just added that line to sites/default/settings.php and reloaded. Unfortunately it still doesn't show old pictures. Only the one which I've added to the new user after migration to D7 was completed.

Comment: Triskelion, I only see a lot of this 'Warnings' in "Recent logs": Warning: Parameter 1 to alinks_node_view() expected to be a reference, value given in module_invoke_all() (line 857 of /home/pharmainfo.net/www/includes/module.inc). But I don't think that has anything to do with the fact that my old images are not appearing. There's also a whole bunch of this messages in apache's error log: [Mon Feb 25 21:21:38 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 79.112.51.100] Zlib: Compressed 19210 to 4550 : URL /index.php, referer: http://www.my-domain.net/

Answer (score 0):

The storage of user pictures changed from D6 to D7. I think the answer for your problem might be found at [Picture Migration](http://drupal.org/node/1819706) on drupal.org.